# Add xml object into another xml object php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml object like this

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file('/path/to/file.xml');
```

i also create one

```
$createdObj = new SimpleXMLElement("<testing></testing>");
```

What i want is tho put the $obj into the $createdObj

So i get

```
<testing>
  <fromobj></fromobj>
</testing>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$createdObj->{$obj->getName()}[] = $obj;
```

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.addchild.php#105158

---

[DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/book.dom.php)-example (supporting any number of child nodes):

```
$doc1 = new DomDocument;
$doc1->load('test.xml');

$doc2 = new DomDocument();
$createdObj = $doc2->appendChild($doc2->createElement('testing'));

$createdObj->appendChild(
  $doc2->importNode($doc1->documentElement, true)
);

echo $doc2->saveXml();
```

Comment: @dfsq This may be true, but honestly, if one has so much xml-manipulation going on the Dom*-functions would be more appropriate.

Comment: thnx m8! that helped me a lot